# windbg losing argument objects after for_each_frame

Tags: windbg

The following script loses the values of arg1 and arg2.
Save this script as "c:\testing.txt"

```
.echo first argument is: ${$arg1}
.echo second argument is: ${$arg2}

~*e .echo thread ; !for_each_frame .echo frame

.echo first argument is: ${$arg1}
.echo second argument is: ${$arg2}
```

Run this script using:
$$a<"c:\testing.txt" alpha bravo

The first two print statements (before the loop) work the last two (after the loop) don't:

**Before the loop:**

```
0:027> $$a<"c:\testing.txt" alpha bravo
0:027> .echo first argument is: ${$arg1}
first argument is: alpha
0:027> .echo second argument is: ${$arg2}
second argument is: bravo
```

**After the loop:**

```
0:027> .echo first argument is: ${$arg1}
first argument is: ${$arg1}
0:027> .echo second argument is: ${$arg2}
second argument is: ${$arg2}
```

Any ideas on why !for_each_frame does this?  If I take out that part and just do the looping through threads I don't lose the value of arg1 and arg2.

I tried storing arg1 and arg2 in aliases - but that didn't help.  Is there any way I can store these argument values before the !for_each_frame so I don't lose them?

I'm using Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 6.2.9200.20512 AMD64

I got this from:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/hardware/hh852363

This script worked in: Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 6.12.0002.633 AMD64

Comment: I can't reproduce the behavior that you're seeing. Are you also seeing this with the 6.2 version of WinDbg?

Comment: Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 6.2.9200.20512 AMD64

Comment: That's crazy... I was sure I had it working yesterday.  And I did.. back when I was using:  Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 6.12.0002.633 AMD64

Comment: What version do you have?  Also, can you think of any way I can work around this?  Save the values somewhere and retrieve them?  I'm just not sure what I can do with variables.

Comment: 6.2 and it works just dandy for me. Not sure what to suggest, it should work.